# Issue with creating an jQuery plugin without selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a jQuery plugin which does not require a selector so I'm just adding it to the global jQuery namespace.

I'm having issues with sharing internal instance variables between my plugin's public methods. For example, I would like to be able to access $.MyPlugin.settings from the .init method.

Here's the plugin code:

```
(function($) {
    $.MyPlugin = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        }

        var plugin = this;

        plugin.settings = {};

        plugin.init = function() {
          plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        }

        plugin.init();
  }

  $.MyPlugin.init = function(callback) {
    console.log(this.settings); // undefined
    callback();
  }


}(jQuery));
```

In main.js, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.MyPlugin({
      username: 'myuser',
      password: 'mypass'
  });

  $.MyPlugin.init(function() {
      console.log('hi');
  });
```

This returns:

```
undefined
hi
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you're coming across is that the data isn't persistent across every instance of your plugin. This is default behaviour but you can get around it using `.data()`:

```
(function ($) {
    $.MyPlugin = function (options) {

        var defaults = {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            },
            plugin = this,
            options = options || {};


        plugin.init = function () {
            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            $.data(document, 'MyPlugin', settings);
        }

        plugin.init();

    }

    $.MyPlugin.init = function (callback) {
        console.log($.data(document, 'MyPlugin'));
        callback();
    }

}(jQuery));
```

This stores your plugin's settings on the `document` element using jQuery's `.data()` function. This doesn't allow for multiple instances of your plugin with separate options though as every re-declaration of `$.MyPlugin`'s options will overwrite the previous ones.

I'm basing my answer on the presumption that you want to use different public methods throughout your script and have them all share the original options. If you're only wanting to call the plugin once then Robert's is probably more in the right direction.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/pPJYx/

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would pass the `init` function along with the options, so you would end up initializing the plugin like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.MyPlugin({
      username: 'myuser',
      password: 'mypass',
      init: function() {
          console.log('hi');
      }
  });
```

And in the plug in, you can call the init function like this:

```
//set the 'this' to the plugin inside init
if (options.init) options.init.call(plugin)
```

Comment: +1 - Nice answer, this might help show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2eMuS/2/